A unique solution of a polynomial differential equation always bounded?
Let say $u(t)$ is known to be a solution to the following differential equation:
$$ u'(t) = a_{1}u(t) + a_{2}u^{2}(t) + ... + a_{n}u^{n}(t) , \\ u(0) = u_{0} \ge 0,  \\ t \in [0, T) $$
does it mean $u(t)$ will be bounded?

Attempt:
Intuitively, the derivative $u'(t)$ will only go to infinity when there is a $t* \in [0, T)$ such that $u(t*) \rightarrow \pm \infty$. Since the initial condition is bounded, then as it grows the derivative will never reach infinity unless maybe when the time limit goes to infinity.
So I would say the solution is always bounded if proven exists.

I do not think this is the case, if not explicilty said. For example, $\tan(t):[0,\frac{\pi}{2})\to \mathbb{R}$ is a (maximal) solution to $u'(t)=1+u^2(t)$ with $u(0)=1$, but it is unbounded.

$u$ will be bounded below, as the zero function is a solution and any other solution can not cross it. If you have a constant solution present with constant value above $x_0$, then $u$ will also be bounded above.
